# Software to use as front-end for a SQL database?

Tags: database, sql

I am looking for an alternative to MS Access. A simple tool that you can design a front-end for the user to be able to connect to database and enter data.

Background;

currently I am using Access as a front-end Form to allow users to scan in data into the database. As the number of records increases it is getting longer to refresh the form and enter the next set of data.

Requirements;

Simple and fast design.
validation of data entered

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [LibreOffice Base](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/):

- Free
- Cross Platform
- Database Back-ends: MySQL/MariaDB, Adabas D, MS Access, PostgreSQL, JDBC & ODBC
- Fast - Yes
- Data Validation - Yes both with form properties & basic macros, (you can also use python as discussed [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python/Transfer_from_Basic_to_Python)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- PostgreSQL
- Django Admin Interface

You define the tables via models in python code. Then you only add a few lines of python and you have got a great and robust solution.

I guess the first days to learn these new things will be hard, but you won't regret it. The community is great. The django docs are great.